# MenuBar.Command() not showing up any results in Vaadin

Tags: java, mysql, menubar, vaadin7

I am creating a menubar dynamically by retrieving the values from MySQL database, checking one of the fields to be true and then accordingly adding menu items to menu bar which is getting correctly implemented. But when I select any of the menu items and tries to print the retrieved text of the selected item then it does not print anything.

My UI class: (Project3UI.java)

```
package com.example.project3;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("mytheme1")
public class Project3UI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*",name = "Servlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = Project3UI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addView("", new MemberStudentView());
        navigator.addView("clubpage", new ClubPage());
    }

}
```

My View Class : (MemberStudentView.java)

```
package com.example.project3;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator;
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.server.ThemeResource;
import com.vaadin.ui.Embedded;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Layout;
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.MenuItem;

@Theme("mytheme1")
public class MemberStudentView extends Panel implements View {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ClubPortalDb";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "xxxx";
    static final String PASS = "xxxxx";
    Navigator navigator;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String cname;
    String status;


     public MemberStudentView() {
            super(new VerticalLayout());
            setCaption("Messages");
            Embedded e = new Embedded();
            e.setSource(new ThemeResource("img/club1.PNG"));
            MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();
            menubar.setWidth("100%");
            MenuItem Clubs = menubar.addItem("MY CLUBS",null,null);
            MenuItem PendingClubs = menubar.addItem("PENDING REQUESTS", null, null);
            ((Layout)getContent()).addComponent(e);
            ((Layout)getContent()).addComponent(menubar);

            try{
                  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                  //STEP 3: Open a connection
                  System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

                  //STEP 4: Execute a query
                  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                  stmt = conn.createStatement();
                  String sql;
                  sql = "Select * from memberStudent WHERE name = 'Priya'";
                  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                  while(rs.next()){
                      cname = rs.getString("ClubName");
                      status = rs.getString("membership_status");
                      if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                          Clubs.addItem(cname, null, null);  
                      }
                      else if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                          PendingClubs.addItem(cname, null, null);  
                      }

                  }
                  rs.close();
                  stmt.close();
                  conn.close();
               }catch(SQLException se){
                  //Handle errors for JDBC
                  se.printStackTrace();
               }catch(Exception e2){
                  //Handle errors for Class.forName
                  e2.printStackTrace();
               }
               System.out.println("Goodbye!");
               MenuBar.Command mycommand = new MenuBar.Command() {
                     public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
                         System.out.println(selectedItem.getText());
                          if(selectedItem.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(cname.toLowerCase()))
                        {
                            System.out.println("cmnm");  
                        }

                          else if(selectedItem.getText().equals("PENDING REQUESTS"))
                        { 
                              System.out.println("cmnp"); 
                        }

                        };
                };

       }
    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
           navigator  = event.getNavigator();
    }



}
```

It just prints

```
Connecting to Database...
Creating statement...
Goodbye!
```

and prints nothing else on the console

I am new to Vaadin.

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: @Peanut : I expect it to print the text of the selected item of the menu which it does not print.. I have mentioned it above .. Please see.